# Question about an audio clip (transcription request)

Tags: listening

I'd appreciate some help.

I'm trying to understand what the man in [the audio file](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=0FD6A27D48C52735&id=FD6A27D48C52735%213103&v=3) says.

I have no idea after he says, "It's going to be very interesting...[???]".

Can you write what he said after that?

Comment: ... few months ahead while the FED works out what's due... is my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit difficult without knowing what they're talking about but I'd guess he says:

> It's going to be a very interesting few months ahead while the [FED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Reserve_System) works out what to do.

Does that make sense in context?

Comment: He kinda "slurs" the last part. It might have been "what to do." (Edit: After listening to it again, I'm %99.999 sure he says "what to do.")

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think I heard "works at" instead of "works out".

Comment: @DamkerngT. "Works at" would not make grammatical sense.